# Wordpress downloads page with upload option

Tags: wordpress, plugins, upload, download

I am quite new to this but what I want to do is create a website that is only accessible over wifi. When the user gets to the website(which I will be using wordpress to build) There needs to be a downloads page with an upload button that allows users to instantly add files to that downloads page.

Does anyone perhaps know of a way to do this? or know of any plugins one can use?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: is it even possible? And if I seem lazy I really cant seem to word this in a way that a search engine understands. So even a push in the right direction in that regard would be great

Answer (score 1):

For the "Security" part (not accessible thru internet), the best is to have your wordpress website hosted on a local server. It makes it unaccessible from internet and will be fast thru wifi network. You can use the domain name of the computer/server (computername.domain.com) to access your website. If you want to use another name eg:mylocalsite.com, you'll have to use a [DNS Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dns_server) to redirect local visitor to your website.

For the plugin, Since there seems to be a lot of plugins that would do the job, i would suggest you to visit [Wordpress plugin repo](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=user+upload) and select the good one that suits your needs (User login or not, only images or files,etc...)